# Super Admins Unable to Publish Entries

Tags: error, permissions

When attempting to publish entries as a super admin, I receive the "You are not authorized to access this page" error. It only happens on specific channels, but these channels don't all share the same field/category groups. Any suggestions/slight inklings greatly appreciated.

EE 2.9.2 / PHP 5.5.9

Comment: Did you check the member group to ensure the group can publish in those channels?

Comment: Does the error happen constantly and can you reproduce reliably? Is this the original Superadmin group, i.e. `group_id == "1"`? Can other groups post without problems?

Comment: It can be reproduced – nobody (in any member group) can post to these channels successfully. And yes, it is the original super admin group. I thought initially it was something to do with a field, but not all of the problem channels share the same field group.